# Help with identifying creature found in brazilian beach

Tags: marine-biology

[image]

I don't know if this is the correct place, but I've been looking for someone 
that could help me identify this creature I found while I was looking for shells. There are three mollusk-like "beings" stuck in some sort of big seed (it's definitely not a rock nor a part of their body). They
 can "spin" around with the arm that is stuck in the seed, and they continuously take some blood red hair-like tentacles in and out of a shell.
I shot a video of it,  the link is right below. Please ignore all background audio, I couldn't find somewhere without people.
This "being" was found today, at roughly 6pm, washed ashore in the beach I'm visiting - "Praia Grande" in Brazil.
Another peculiar thing is that tap water makes the "things" close for a while, and sea water doesn't do much. Also, as they dried, the single tentacle hair became multiple smaller ones. They keep coming in and out, without stop.

If anyone could give me a shine on what that animal is, it would be super helpful!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-rSk-WVb6pkS98Npp1VF3Aq8xxXPKiuc/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE. I suspect you're not getting a response to your question because the thing that makes the question answerable - the video - is at an external site. That can cause problems down the line (for instance, if Google changes its linking structures, the question becomes uncheckable). It is possible to add video to questions, but according to this question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248249/is-it-possible-to-embed-videos-in-questions), only via youtube link. Alternatively, you could take a couple of screen-captures from the video and add them.

Answer (score 1):

Those are [gooseneck barnacles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goose_barnacle) possibly [pelagic gooseneck barnacles (*Lepas_anatifera*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepas_anatifera).

For comparison:
[image: Lepas anatifera — Contributor: Top Photo Corporation / Alamy Stock Photo]

A beautiful picture and description can be seen [here](https://alexhyde.photoshelter.com/image/I00001iutXmwdGPU).